# the derivative of: $f(x)= x-2\text{arctan}(x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inverse-function

Now, I know that this will just become $1-\frac{2}{x^2+1}$ if I apply the derivative of arctan, but how can I calculate the derivative of this function, step by step? 
I am already lost at the beginning. If $f(x)=\text{arctan}(x)$ instead I would just substitute it so that $\text{tan}(y) = x$ and then use implicit differentiation, but I don't  know where to start with the function in the title.

Comment: You can just apply the linearity of the derivative.

Comment: What do you mean by step? Do you mean from first principles?

Comment: Well I know that (d/dx)(tan^-1(x)) = 1/(1+x^2), but what if I didn't know that initially. How would I get from f(x) to the derivative then? This is what I mean by step, basically the manipulation that would led me there. Not sure what you meant by from first principle?

Comment: If $F=f+g$ and both $f$ and $g$ are differentiable at $x$, then also $F$ is differentiable at $x$, with $F'(x)=f'(x)+g'(x)$. Since you already know the derivative of the arctangent, what's the point in computing it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to apply this method then we would have
$$y=x-2\arctan{(x)}$$
$$x=\tan{\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)}$$
Which we can differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ giving
$$1=\sec^2{\left(\frac{x-y}2\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{1-y'}2\right)$$
$$1=(1+x^2)\cdot\left(\frac{1-y'}2\right)$$
$$\frac{1-y'}2=\frac1{1+x^2}$$
$$1-y'=\frac2{1+x^2}$$
$$y'=1-\frac2{1+x^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: This begs the question: how do you know that $y$ is differentiable?